# Swift: Byte array to decimal value

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte

In my project, I communicate with a bluetooth device, the bluetooth device must send me a timestamp second, I received in byte:

```
[2,6,239]
```

When I convert converted to a string:

```
let payloadString = payload.map {
            String(format: "%02x", $0)
        }
```

Output:

```
["02", "06","ef"]
```

When I converted from the [website](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) 0206ef = 132847 seconds

How can I directly convert my aray `[2,6,239]` in second (= 132847 seconds)?
And if it's complicated then translate my array `["02", "06,"ef"]` in second (= 132847 seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payload contains the bytes of the binary representation of the value.
You convert it back to the value by shifting each byte into its corresponding position:

```
let payload: [UInt8] = [2, 6, 239]
let value = Int(payload[0]) << 16 + Int(payload[1]) << 8 + Int(payload[2])
print(value) // 132847
```

The important point is to convert the bytes to integers *before* shifting, otherwise an overflow error would occur. Alternatively,
with multiplication:

```
let value = (Int(payload[0]) * 256 + Int(payload[1])) * 256 + Int(payload[2])
```

or

```
let value = payload.reduce(0) { $0 * 256 + Int($1) }
```

The last approach works with an arbitrary number of bytes – as long as
the result fits into an `Int`. For 4...8 bytes you better choose `UInt64`
to avoid overflow errors:

```
let value = payload.reduce(0) { $0 * 256 + UInt64($1) }
```

Comment: I do not understand why the shift is not always the same, you write once << 16, then, << 8, then for the last nothing why?
Same with the multiplication why the last you do not multiply it?

Comment: It is possible that the device does not send me 3 byte but 4 so how should I do?

Comment: If the device sends me 4byte instead of 3 [2,3,6,222] the code remains the same?

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen: I added a version with works with a variable number of bytes.

Comment: The latest version is generic? for more bytes?

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen: Think of decimal numbers: 427 = 4 * 10^2 + 2 *10 + 7 = (4 * 10 + 2) * 10 + 7. In the same way, the bytes (2,3,6) represent the value 2 * 256^2 + 3 * 256 + 6 = (2 * 256 + 3) * 256 + 6. – Yes, the last version is generic. It is only assumed that the result fits into an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation, I appreciate a lot

Comment: The last two generic versions do not work, [233, 0, 0, 0]. Output loong number ..

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen: [233, 0, 0, 0] is 0xE9, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00. If you enter E9000000 on https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter then you'll get the same result 3909091328. – What result do you expect?

Comment: Ah yes it works, I needed that if the value is 0 must I remove it from the array

Comment: @Carpsen90: That is correct. But in the early days of Swift it used to run on 32-bit devices as well (e.g. iPhone 5). Swift is also ported to many other platforms, are they all 64-bit? – Anyway, as long as Swift documents Int as 32 *or* 64-bit integers, I prefer to use fixed-size types if I *know* that I need a certain size. – Btw, even on a 64-bit platform the above code would overflow for `[128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` because that does not fit into a *signed* 64-bit int.

Comment: @Carpsen90: I'll add something later, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

`payloadString` string can be reduced to `hexStr` and then converted to decimal

```
var payload = [2,6,239];
let payloadString = payload.map {
    String(format: "%02x", $0)
}

//let hexStr = payloadString.reduce(""){$0 + $1}
let hexStr = payloadString.joined()
if let value = UInt64(hexStr, radix: 16) {
    print(value)//132847
}
```

Comment: If the device sends me 4byte instead of 3 [2,3,6,222] the code remains the same?

Comment: yes code will remain same for 4byte or more. For [2,3,6,222] output will be 33752798 with same above code.

Comment: Note that `payloadString.reduce(""){$0 + $1}` can be simplified to `payloadString.joined()`

Comment: Correctly pointed, that's a better easier way. Updated answer.